# How to invoke Explicit wait to click on the element with text as My Account through Selenium and Java within the website https://www.phptravels.net

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am writing the following code to click on the element with text as **My Account**. It is showing "element not visible". To resolve the issue I am trying expected wait, but it is being timed out. Is there any way around. You can find my code below:

```
package com.php.travels;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LogIn {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty(
      "webdriver.chrome.driver", 
      "/Users/owner/desktop/chromedriver");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net");
    try {
       WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
            By.xpath("//li[@id ='li_myaccount']/a"))
       ).click();

    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        System.out.println("The execption is: " + t);
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("If no exception tell me now");
    }
}

} // end class
```

Comment: If the `ExpectedCondition` times out this can either mean (1) that you have to wait for a longer period or (2) some page logic condition is not met so that the element is not visible.Find out about that by manually doing what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **My Account** instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* through **`elementToBeClickable()`** method and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.phptravels.net");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//nav[@class='navbar navbar-default']//li[@id='li_myaccount']/a[normalize-space()='My Account']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: php_travels_login_click]

Comment: Hi Debanjan, your solution is working on my end also. Thank you. However, I do not understand the xpath you write. How did you get this xpath?Can you please help me by explaining?

Comment: The _xpath_ which you have used doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely. It identified 2 elements and the first element was a hidden element. So we have constructed a unique _xpath_ to identify the element.