# xpath on auto-suggestive text automating travelocity.com fails

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have been trying many ways to generate correct xpath for clicking the first auto-suggested text on travelocity.com.But the xpath is failing to locate the element. Below is my code. Can anybody help me with the correct xpath, please.

```
package com.travel.city;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Booking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/owner/desktop/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.travelocity.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("tab-flight-tab-hp")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin-hp-flight")).sendKeys("LAX");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='multiLineDisplay'] [contains(text(),'Los Angeles, CA, United States')]/parent::span[@class='text']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("flight-destination-hp-flight")).sendKeys("DEN");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='multiLineDisplay']/[contains(text(),'Denver, United States of America')]/parent::span[@class='text']")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: In order t ohelp you with correct xpath, We need HTML snippet. Also, you need to share error stack.

Comment: @ShahidIslam Did you work with the answers provided to two of ur previous question [Both of the input box has exactly same attributes. How do I take unique xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296489/both-of-the-input-box-has-exactly-same-attributes-how-do-i-take-unique-xpath) and [How to invoke Explicit wait to click on the element with text as Login through Selenium and Java within the website https://www.phptravels.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278500/how-to-invoke-explicit-wait-to-click-on-the-element-with-text-as-login-through-s). Conceptually this question is a dup,

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things. First, improve your test organization by using WebDriverWait object for suggestions waiting, and second, debug your xpath locators in chrome console before writing the code. In your code snippet, both locators are incorrect.
This should do better:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    driver.get("http://www.travelocity.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("tab-flight-tab-hp")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin-hp-flight")).sendKeys("LAX");
    wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                    By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Los Angeles, CA, United States')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "//div[contains(text(), 'Los Angeles, CA, United States')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("flight-destination-hp-flight")).sendKeys("DEN");
    wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
                    "//a[@data-value = 'Denver (DEN-All Airports)']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "//a[@data-value = 'Denver (DEN-All Airports)']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you. However, Denver(DEN-All Airports finds the element, but not clicking to select. I tried also tried Denver, CO (DEN-Denver Intl.).  Same thing is happening here also; its is finding the element but not clicking the element to select.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your xpath as below.

**Working Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.travelocity.com");
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Wander"));


    driver.findElement(By.id("tab-flight-tab-hp")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin-hp-flight")).sendKeys("LAX");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='results']//div[@class='multiLineDisplay' and contains(text(),'Los Angeles, CA, United States')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("flight-destination-hp-flight")).sendKeys("DEN");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='results']//div[@class='multiLineDisplay' and contains(text(),'United States of America')]")).click();

}
```